# Convert nan to integer but get generic value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column of data and I am trying to remove decimal places from the data to get

```
56008265990
56013205307
etc.
```

It currently looks like this when I read it into python.

```
0       56008265990.000
1       56013205307.000
2       56000116799.000
3       56000959848.000
4       56010419025.000
              ...      
49056   56000818137.000
49057   56000146564.000
49058   56001739190.000
49059   56002050665.000
49060   56003026564.000
Name: ID, Length: 49061, dtype: float64
```

There are some values with nan

I am running

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(0)

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)
```

But when I print the result I am getting this output

```
0       -2147483648
1       -2147483648
2       -2147483648
3       -2147483648
4       -2147483648
            ...    
49056   -2147483648
49057   -2147483648
49058   -2147483648
49059   -2147483648
49060   -2147483648
Name: ID, Length: 49061, dtype: int32
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['ID'].astype(np.int64)
```

The reason is that `int` type is limited to -2147483648 through 2147483647 and your numbers are out of [limitations][1].

```
56008265990.000>2147483647
```

On the other hand `np.int64` is limited by `-2**63` to `2**63 - 1`, which is in accordance with your needs.

[1]: [http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/#:~:text=These%20represent%20numbers%20in%20the,size%2C%20but%20not%20smaller.](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/#:%7E:text=These%20represent%20numbers%20in%20the,size%2C%20but%20not%20smaller.))

Answer (score 1):

Use `int64` for correct casting:

```
import numpy as np

df['ID'] = df['ID'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
print (df)
            ID
0  56008265990
1  56013205307
2  56000116799
3  56000959848
4  56010419025
```